# Xcode 6: Error copying template database

Tags: ios, xcode

For my app I am trying to implement Vungle Video ads. I had no problem integrating the code and SDK, but once try to run my app, it does not even start and I get this error:

> Error copying template database. Make sure you added the Vungle.embeddedframework to your project!
>   Assertion failed: (false), function -[VungleSDK loadDatabase], file /Users/rolando.abarca/Documents/vungle/ios-sdk-for-real/source/VungleSDK.m, line 990.

I have the Vungle framework added and it appears in Linked Frameworks and Libraries. I also have #import  at the top of my delegate and view controller files. I'm sure there has to be something simple I'm missing but I cannot figure it out for the life of me!

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: any progress on this, I am facing same issue?

Comment: @Yadnesh I do not remember exactly what I did for this issue... I may have went into my apps folder in finder and deleted the vungle file and started over. However, I ended up not using Vungle because it interfered with the other ad company I was using for interstitials. The error in this question may have been the error I could not fix because of the other ad company

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply, It got solved for me it needed two things to be put into projects from Vungle sdk zip file, one was VungleSDK.framework other was the Resources/ folder, i wasnt doing the later part

Comment: any luck with that? I have the framework file and resources also and still having the same issue

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are importing `VungleSDK.framework` and the folder Resources. To solve it you must import in your project the folder `VungleSDK.embeddedframework` (which contains the framework and resources folder), not the framework and resources folder separately.

UPDATE: make sure that when importing `VungleSDK.embeddedframework` you check **Copy items if needed** and **Create groups** to make this solution work.